# ASP MVC 4 - Error while adding foreign Key in UserProfile table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, security

In ASP MVC, I updated `UserProfile` table using code first like this

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set;}

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

P.S. State is a foreign key to another table.

I tried to insert user using following statement

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email, State = state });
```

I get error

> "No mapping exists from object type State to a known managed provider
>   native type".

I cannot figure out why the mapping does not exist.

Comment: did u get any solution for this ?

Comment: Websecurity uses its owns dbcontext. Somehow I could not find it. Instead of creating a foreign key I simply created a column and solved the problem. P.S. WebSecurity class is immature and has some problems.